# Checking monotonic sequences - C programming

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

I am doing a problem about checking monotonic sequences. The problem is inputting a sequence and then print "YES" if it is monotonic, "NO" if it is not.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //Inputting the sequence
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
    }

    
    //Checking monotonic sequence
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if ((a[i] > a[i-1]) && (a[i] > a[i+1]))
            {
                printf("NO");
                return;
            }
        else if ((a[i] < a[i-1]) && (a[i] < a[i+1]))
            {
                printf("NO");
                return;
            }
        
    }
    printf("YES");

    return 0;
}
```

I have failed 2 test case with sequences [1, 2, 3] and [10, 6, 4, 2, 1, -100]; and passed one test case with [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]. Can anyone please point out the problem in my code? I would truly appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing your program does wrong with the problematic test cases?

Comment: How are you allocating a static array where its size is dynamic (`n`  is got by input)? Does this program compile?

Comment: @MatteoGalletta "How are you allocating a static array where its size is dynamic " --> Since C99 (20+ years), C has offered [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove trailing `" "`.  It obliges additional input (or end-of-file) after the number is entered before `scanf()` returns.

```
// scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

---

In addition to index problems in 2 places, code needs to look for overall monotonic and not just local monotonic behavior.

```
bool up = true;
bool down = true;

// for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] > a[i-1]) down = false;
  if (a[i] < a[i-1]) up = false;
}

printf((up || down) ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Additional code to short-circuit loop.

```
// for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
for (int i = 1; i < n && (up || down); i++) {
```

Further there is lack of the coding goal clarity on tie cases.  May need

```
  if (a[i] >= a[i-1]) down = false;
  if (a[i] <= a[i-1]) up = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` has indices from 0 to `n`-1; you code references `a[0]` (which never gets assigned to) and `a[n]` (which is outside the bounds of the array).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking with invalid array index. here you are declaring an array size of `n` but you are checking with `i+1` that means `n+1` for the last case. This is out of bound for your array. First of all you are storing data in array from `1` to `n` . But when you declare a array size `n` then it has index from `0` to `n-1`.so you can store data from `0` to `n` and start the check from `1` and end in `n-1`.

this one will work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  //Inputting the sequence
  int n;
  scanf ("%d", &n);
  int a[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    }


  int inc = 0;
  int dec = 0;
  //Checking monotonic sequence
  for (int i = 1; i < n ; i++)
    {

      if (a[i] > a[i - 1])
    {
      inc = 1;
    }
      else if (a[i] < a[i - 1])
    {
      dec = 1;
    }

    }
  if (inc == 1 && dec == 1)
    {

      printf ("NO");
    }
  else
    {

      printf ("YES");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried submitting your code but it does not work for the case [1,2,3,3,2,1]

Comment: @GarrickJay i have updated my ans . can you try the updated one please?

Comment: I have tried it and it's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @GarrickJay if the answer work for you . Acceptance of the answer will be more appreciable.